# On the interpretation of functional and vanishing of Russel's paradox in Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus

Tags: wittgenstein

> 3.333 A function cannot be its own argument, because the functional
> sign already contains the prototype of its own argument and it
> cannot contain itself.
> If, for example, we suppose that the function F(fx) could
> be its own argument, then there would be a proposition
> “F(F(fx))”, and in this the outer function F and the inner
> function F must have different meanings; for the inner has
> the form φ(fx), the outer the form ψ(φ(fx)). Common to
> both functions is only the letter “F”, which by itself signifies
> nothing.
> **This is at once clear, if instead of “F(F(u))” we write “(∃φ) :
> F(φu) . φu = F u”.
> Herewith Russell’s paradox vanishes.**

I fairly understand what the author means here, but it is in the bold part that I'm having difficult understanding what is meant. I don't understand why the function φ should be unique in this case, and how it relates to Russel's paradox.

Comment: @ClydeFrog Yes these answers were helpful and I understand it now. It is going to sound dumb, but I must be honest, I kept interpreting the period as a multiplier symbol and that completely threw me off.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta get into this notation. Have fun with Wittgenstein!